# How to Get Designer.cs to access other classes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, print-preview

The back story is that to organize my code I made a new class called Printing.cs and dumped my code there from my main.cs. 
In my designer.cs  I have this:  `this.DVPrintDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(this.DVPrintDocument_PrintPage);`I am getting an error message saying does not contain definition and no extension method found. How can I make it so Designer.cs can access other classes?

This is the class I want the designer.cs to look at:

```
using static TicketingSystem.TicketingSystem;

namespace TicketingSystem
{
   class Printing
   {
    TicketingSystem ticketingSystem;
        public Printing(TicketingSystem ticketingSystem) => 
this.ticketingSystem = ticketingSystem;


    public void DVPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap r3tsLogo = Properties.Resources.rt3slogo;
        Image image1 = r3tsLogo; //image 1 is r3tsLogo
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image1, 350, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height);
        // e.Graphics.DrawString("Employee Name:" + employee.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 200)); //Put to bottom of paper
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Address:", new Font("Impact", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(300, 90));//change the new point to put text on different part of paper.
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Room 61", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(370, 94)); //This line of code connects to Code line 151   
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Email:", new Font("Impact", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(300, 120));//change the new point to put text on different part of paper.
        e.Graphics.DrawString("email@email.com", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(350, 124)); //This line of code connects to Code line 154
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Date: " + DateTime.Now, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(300, 150));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ticketingSystem.dashes.Text, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 160));
      }
```

Sorry I am still learning C# but this a project for my school class. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Did you add namespace of designer.cs in printing.cs?

Comment: No, to my knowledge I don't think I can do that. Please correct me if I am wrong? @VijayanathViswanathan

Comment: If both of your classes are in the same assembly please add namespace of designer.cs. if not in same assembly please add a library reference and add namespace.

Comment: Could you please show me some code? As visualization helps me much better @VijayanathViswanathan

Answer (score 0):

The formXXXX.designer.cs file is generated by the WinForms designer to keep your user interface objects and initialize their properties with the settings you make through the Winform Designer interface.
As such file is created and maintained by the WinForms infrastructure you shouldn't try to add your own code or manually change anything here.
(Besides, every time you change your form, this file is rewritten)

So, you simply need to add back the event handler *DVPrintDocument_PrintPage* to your main form as it was before. But none blocks you from writing something in your event handler that calls the code in the Printing class.

Something like this

In your main form.cs file readd the event handler for DVPrintDocument

```
public void DVPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
     Printing print = new Printing(ticketingSystem);
     print.PrintPageHandler(sender, e);
}
```

in your Printing class

```
public class Printing
{
    TicketingSystem ticketingSystem;
    public Printing(TicketingSystem ticketingSystem) => 
                    this.ticketingSystem = ticketingSystem;


    public void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap r3tsLogo = Properties.Resources.rt3slogo;
        Image image1 = r3tsLogo; //image 1 is r3tsLogo
        // remainder of your current code 
       .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am doing the same as you said. All steps worked except Printing printing = new Printing(ticketingSystem); ticketingSystem gives me an error saying does not exist in the current context. I know what the error means and did try to resolve that with TicketingSystem ticketingSystem = new TicketingSystem(); but it did not work.

Comment: Your Printing class requires an instance of TicketingSystem. You should have an instance of this class when you call the constructor of Printing class. From the code provided I can suppose that this TicketingSystem is the name of the form that calls the Printing class. In this case just pass _this_ as parameter to the Printing class constructor